# Find the Center and Radius of a Circle with a Given Circle Equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, circles

There is a question that is asking the center and radius of the circle that is defined by the equation $x^2 + y^2 - 2ax + 4by =0$.

This was my work (completing the square):
$$x^2 - 2ax + (\frac{-2a}{2})^2 + y^2 + 4by + (\frac{4b}{2})^2 = (\frac{-2a}{2})^2 + (\frac{4b}{2})^2$$
$$x^2 - 2ax + a^2 + y^2 + 4by + 4b^2 = a^2 + 4b^2$$
$$(x-a)^2 + (y-2b)^2 = a^2 + 4b^2$$

I got the center of the circle to be $(a,  2b)$, and the radius of the circle to be $\sqrt{a^2 + 4b^2}$ (although I don't know how to simplify the radius any further than that).

Am I wrong in any step?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry but MSE is not to double check your homework. It is not that much work, you can check it yourself

Comment: But I need help in understanding whether what I did was correct or incorrect. I don't know what to do, this was just my attempt. MSE, for me, is a place where I can learn and correct myself whenever I am misunderstanding something.

Comment: You have a sign error, and that radius cannot be simplified.

Comment: You can begin increasing your understanding by checking your own work. Plug $x=a+\sqrt{a^2+4b^2}$ and $y=2b$ into the equation and see what you get. If it’s not zero, then you’ve definitely made a mistake somewhere and have starting point for figuring out what went wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is almost correct but you have switched signs in the last equation. It should be $(y+2b)^2$ and not $(y-2b)^2$.

Comment: So the center would be: $(a, -2b)$. The radius: $\sqrt{a^2+4b^2}$. Are those answers correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Note $(x - a)^2 = x^2 - 2ax + a^2$ , so $x^2 - 2ax = (x - a)^2 - a^2$. Also note that $(y + 2b)^2 = y^2 + 4by + 4b^2$, so $y^2 + 4by = (y + 2b)^2 - 4b^2$. So the equation becomes, $(x - a)^2 - a^2 + (y + 2b)^2 - 4b^2 = 0$. This implies that,
$(x - a)^2 + (y + 2b)^2 = a^2 + 4b^2$. Thus this is a circle with center $(a, -2b)$ and radius $\sqrt{a^2 + 4b^2}$.

Answer (score 1):

$$x^2+y^2−2ax+4by=0$$

Using method of completing the square

$$x^2-2ax+(-a)^2-(-a)^2+y^2+4by+(2b)^2-(2b)^2=0$$

$$(x-a)^2+(y+2b)^2=a^2+4b^2$$

The center of the circle is given as

$$(a,-2b)$$

The radius of the circle is

$$r^2=a^2+4b^2$$

$$r=\sqrt{a^2+4b^2}$$

Consider the general form of equation for object circle,

$$(x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2=r^2$$

Center is then

$$(x_0,y_0)$$

The radius is then
$$r$$

There is a mistake of the sign in your work.